# Send AT command from Android to USB port

Tags: android, usb, at-command

Hello fellow programmers,
I've got a question regarding the realisation of an app which should be able to send AT commands via USB to a connected hardware.

Is it possible to send these commands over USB without root? I would not want to have rooted phones as target market as I want the application to be useable for the average Android platform. Is there any solution out there which you know and can give some links to that?

cheers
herom

Comment: if the phones support the optional usb host api then yes.  If not, no, unless you have one that can be made a usb host via kernel modifications (requiring root or more)

Comment: hey chris, thanks for your reply. so it would be limited to Android 3.0 and upwards?

Comment: more specifically, to devices which support that optional feature

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I know it's a long time ago, but would you please consider to post your first comment as an answer so I could mark this question as solved? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the phones support the optional usb host api then likely yes.   You will probably need a USB-OTG style adapter cable which grounds the extra pin to help put the phone in host mode.

If not, no, unless you have one that can be made a usb host via kernel modifications (requiring root, likely kernel reflashing, and possibly a special cable to inject power)